# Download Sharepoint xlsx file with R Project?

Tags: r, sharepoint, download

Anyone know how i can download Sharepoint .xlsx files with R Project?

I try with httr and downloader library

Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(readxl)
url <- "https://sharepoint.mycompany.ca/teams/report/file.xlsx"
download.file(url = url, destfile = "D:/file.xlsx", mode = "wb")
read_excel("D:/file.xlsx")
```